# Symfony Maximum Number of Routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am looking at a very large routing file (2k), I was just wondering if anyone else has had experience with large routing files and what kind of performance issues there were (if any)?

Comment: Cannot imagine what kind of application need 2k routes...

Comment: If there would be performances issues, I guess it could be reduced by making sub-file. Else, @malcolm is right, 2k rout is... special

Comment: Just looking at my options, it is a huge website (£30 million business and growing fast), just trying to simplify things as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This depends of your memory size of opcode PHP or your cache system because all of your implementations of routing symfony is translate into opcode.

You are a very very large size by default but the limit depends on you.